# Clustering on Raw Image Pixel Array

Tags: clustering, image-preprocessing

I have an array in the shape of (105, 105, 3). When I do plt.imshow(array) it outputs:
[image]

How can I run a clustering algorithm directly on this image? Do I need to convert the pixels to cartesian coordinates and if so, how?

I have tried:

```
labels = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2).fit(array).predict(array)
```

However this outputs an error. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, a clustering algorithm such as Gaussian Mixture Model would require cartesian coordinates.

This can be done as follows to get the coordinates of the dark pixels:

```
import numpy as np

binary = np.mean(array, axis=2) < 0.5
X = np.stack(np.where(binary)).transpose()
```

You should now be able to cluster `X`

**Note:** For images, segmentation is more common than clustering. Both types of processing are related and segmentation can be seen as a special kind of clustering, but often aims for sligtly different outcomes.
Not knowing your desired outcome, I just want to hint you to these kind of algorithms in case they fit to your task.